# java maven needs to different versions of a library

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml

I need Library L version A and version B the same time.

<-Dependencies->

```
  <-Dependency->

        Library L of version A
  <-/Dependency->
  <-Dependency->
        Third party library (needs Library L of version B)
  <-/Dependency->
```

<-/Dependencies->

If I write like the above, the third party library also recruit Library L of verions A, not version B.  Then it will throw some errors, how should I claim pom to make it work?

Btw, have to use wired <-  ->  mark, otherwise, format is messed up.

Please help still looking for an answer

Thanks

Comment: you cannot do this in a single classloader.  you _can_ load 2 different versions of the same library in _separate_ classloaders, but you would have to do a lot of tricky things to make it work.  i would try to figure out how to make things work with _one_ version of the library.

Comment: if you are trying to include _both_ versions in a single classloader, no, there is no solution.  if you are trying to make maven resolve a single, specific version, then that is fairly trivial.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have same artifact's two version by default,

assume even you hacked it to make it working, at runtime the first one which is in the classpath order will get precedence so it is really very bad idae to do

Comment: It is true that it is not a good idea.  But when I have to it, how should I configure?

Comment: how do you run your app ?

Comment: build a war and deploy a war to tomcat

Comment: if you use assembly plugin you can push particular jar at particular place in war file, so place that jar file to `WEB-INF/lib` by configuration

Comment: do you have any keywords for assembly plugin, so that I can quickly search on how to do that?  Thanks